# Selenium Prevent chromedriver New Window from getting Focus on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-chromedriver

I have a selenium script that scraps a website. Each time selenium driver opens a new link, the Chrome driver launches a new instance of Google Chrome and provides input to a search query using `send_keys`.
And, the newly opened chrome tab appears in front of any other windows (i.e Nautilus or say Firefox) open on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I tried running the script in different workspace but still it automatically switches workspace to show the newly opened chrome tab (by the script).
Also, Even if I make the currently visible window `Always on top` by right clicking on the Title bar. It still loses focus as soon as the chrome browser opens the link (On the other workspaces)

Is there any way to prevent chrome driver's newly opened tab from getting focus?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, but will let other pitch in if they have a solution

Comment: I tried `devilspie2` as well(according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/650709) ), but no luck... I guess you are right. @TarunLalwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution for `chromedriver` so, I just switched back to `phantomjs` again.

Download link of PhantomJS: http://phantomjs.org/download.html

Answer (score 1):

Start  a headless browser can be an option

```
final var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--headless");

final var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```